# Cake.Build doesn't generate description for nuget and non-sdk projecs

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, csproj, cakebuild

I have quite simple nuget package creating logic with cake.build:

```
            var nugetSettings = new NuGetPackSettings
            {
                OutputDirectory = "%some_path%",
                Verbosity = NuGetVerbosity.Detailed,
                Description = "oops, description",
                Version = "2.0.0"
            };

            context.NuGetPack("%project_path%", nugetSettings);
```

It generates nguet package and set expected version, but the description value is ignored. This is what I still see in `ClassLibrary1.2.0.0.nupkg`:

[image]

Target framework:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

`Description` value is not appeared in the package metadata even if I manually add `Description` property to the `.csproj` file like:

```
<Description>asd</Description>
```

Comment: Is cake building the package via msbuild and NuGet's pack targets, or using `nuget.exe pack` with a nuspec file?  The `<Description>` msbuild property only works with NuGet's MSBuild pack target, not `nuget.exe pack`.

Comment: It looks like this is the reason (then it's a bug in Cake I guess). Is there a way to specify description for `nuget.exe pack`?

Comment: to highlight and cc: @zivkan

Comment: typically with `dotnet pack` you provide your own nuspec, so you'd put it in there. Look up nuget's nuspec reference documentation. it had the entire schema listed.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `NuGetPack` (like nuget.exe) has two very distinct usages: One operating on a project file and one operating on a `.nuspec` file and not all settings that are available in the `NuGetPackSettings` are used for both usages.

The documentation (and maybe a warning during runtime) should probably make this more obvious.